# Determining when to use Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Looking at a lot of MVC source code, I notice that most MVC projects (especially larger projects) implement dependency injection in one way or another.

I have two questions. First of all, is it feasible to create a large project without using dependency injection? I understand dependency injection makes large projects a lot easier to maintain and unit test. But how much more complex would a project be that didn't use dependency injection?

Second, when scoping the requirements of a new project, what criteria should I use to determine if I should use dependency injection? It requires a lot of initial setup and sometimes it seems unnecessary for a quick simple program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing like wrong or useless dependency injection so i recommend to use it always :)

It makes your code much more extensible, easier to test and also more readable (because the dependencies are clearly visible).

> Second, when scoping the requirements of a new project, what criteria
>   should I use to determine if I should use dependency injection?

- You can avoid it for prototyping or if you are
  building something which will be not used in production environment.

> it feasible to create a large project without using dependency
>   injection?

- yes but i do not recommend to do this

> It requires a lot of initial setup and sometimes it seems unnecessary
>   for a quick simple program.

- Asp.MVC has good built in support for dependency injection. You can setup it pretty quickly. It is only matter of a [nuget package instalation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/).

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DonBoitnott looks still like a comment?

Comment: Better.  But instead of posting a non-answer just to be first, try posting the whole answer once.